# Grep to be displayed with value from ISF

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

Currently i have a list that i use ISF function with grep to display just one value from ISF.

```
EX:

LST Q: USER="000111222333";%%

NAME                           CATEGORY


TESTING                        2A
```

when i use the below command:

```
IFS=$'\n'; cat > test7; cat test7 | grep "LST Q: USER=" | awk -F'"' '{print$2}'
```

and paste my list I can get the value for USER only. But now i want the value for USER and the value under the NAME. Kindly assist. Thanks.

PS:The format of the list is as shown above. Not changeable.

Comment: `cat | grep | awk` is [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)...

Comment: you can use `grep -A 2`. But doing it with pure awk is much easier... All it would take is a bit of state-machine like implementation. `awk '/LST Q: USER=/{user=gensub(/[^"]*"([^"]*)".*/,"\\1","",$0);} user && NF {name=$2; print user; print name; user="";}'`

Comment: Hi anishsasne, Can you please explain the command? Sorry, kind of noob. and another thing is it possible to just display the records with specific name? I have several names like TESTING, TESTING1 and so on. If i want to display just TESTING, can it be done?

Comment: First part checks for string `/LST Q: USER=` & sets a script variable `user` to the value between quotes. next line onwards, when `user` is set & line is non empty, it sets the `name` to 2nd field. Prints `user` & `name` & then un-sets `user`.

Comment: I am getting an error as below:

`awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=5) warning: gensub: third argument ``' treated as 1
000111222333
Q:`

Comment: that's a warning. You may change `""` to `1`.

Comment: Now I'm getting the USER value plus "Q". Not the NAME value

Comment: Fixed: `awk '/LST Q: USER=/{user=gensub(/[^"]*"([^"]*)".*/,"\\1","",$0);next;} user && NF {name=$2; print user; print name; user="";}'`

Comment: Hey sorry, but it gives the same error as above.

Comment: You want value 'under' NAME? I misinterpreted it then...

Comment: `awk '/LST Q: USER=/{print gensub(/[^"]*"([^"]*)".*/,"\\1",1,$0);} /^NAME/{flag=1; next;} flag && NF{print $1; flag=0}' test.txt`

Comment: It works now. But it returns USER value twice and only one value under NAME. Sorry, probably I wasn't clear. There might be more than one value under NAME sometimes.

Comment: & How can you understand how many values are under NAME?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find the name:

```
awk -F" " 'BEGIN{find=0} { if($1=="NAME") {find=1; next} if(find==1) {print $1;find=0;}}' test7
```

---

**DEMO**

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ cat test7
EX:
LST Q: USER="000111222333";%%
NAME                           CATEGORY
TESTING                        2A
lo@ubuntu:~$ awk -F" " 'BEGIN{find=0} { if($1=="NAME") {find=1; next} if(find==1) {print $1;find=0;}}' test7 
TESTING
```

Comment: This command doesn't work as well. It just returns back the command.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It just gives back 

`awk -F" " 'BEGIN{find=0} { if($1=="NAME") {find=1; next} if(find==1) {print $1;find=0;}}' test7`

Comment: Well, I'm still confusing about what you are expecting for. I add a demo.

Comment: Can you please explain your code? Perhaps I can understand where it went wrong.

Comment: I set a flag when I found `NAME`. The line after the line coursed the flag set contains the `NAME`. So I print the `NAME` and unset the flag.